# itext pdf with com.lowagie.text.table

Tags: itext

how to avoid space or gap between two tables in iText 
using the class com.lowagie.text.table

```
    Table table;
    com.lowagie.text.Cell cell;
    table = new Table(2);
    table.setPadding(2);
    table.setWidths(new int[] {100});
    table.setWidth(100);
    cell = new com.lowagie.text.Cell(new Phrase(
            "sample text1", FontFactory
                    .getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, commonfontsize)));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    cell.setBorder(0);
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
    table = new Table(2);
    table.setPadding(2);
    table.setWidths(new int[] {50,50});
    table.setWidth(100);
    cell = new com.lowagie.text.Cell(new Phrase(
            "sample text1", FontFactory
                    .getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, commonfontsize)));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    cell.setBorder(0);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new com.lowagie.text.Cell(new Phrase(
            "sample text2", FontFactory
                    .getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10)));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.setBorder(0);
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
```

how to remove the space between the first table and second table?

Comment: The `Table` class has been abandoned many years ago. So has the version of iText you are using. I suggest that you start using `PdfPTable` instead of `Table` (a real must!) and that you upgrade to a version of iText that doesn't mention my name in the package names. (I am the Lowagie you are referring to in your code!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give spaces before and after the `PdfTable table`

```
table.setSpacingBefore();      

table.setSpacingAfter();
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply                                            i need to avoid the default gap between two tables,                that means no space between tables

Comment: try this `tb1.setSpacingBefore(0f);` where tb1 is the second table object

Comment: i'am not using PdfPTable, i'am using com.lowagie.text.Table and its having only setSpacing() method

Comment: i dint find any method in com.lowagie.text.Table which removes the space from the previous component why dont you switch to [com.itextpdf](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.0.6)

Comment: i'am using pdfwriter and rtfwriter for same code depending on the user selection but in case if i  use itextpdf i think the code should also be changed

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876678/itext-5-0-0-where-did-rtf-and-html-go) might help you